# real analysis functions and interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x) = x^2$. Assume $A$ is the interval $[0,4]$ and $B$ is the interval $[−1,1]$. Does $f^{−1}(A \cap B) = f^{−1}(A) \cap f^{−1}(B)$? Does $f^{−1}(A \cup B) = f^{−1}(A) \cup f^{−1}(B)$? If so do they hold in a more general situation? Prove or disprove your statement. When I solved it,I encounter complex numbers.How can I solve another way?

inverse of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and on $[-1,1]$ is it false?

$f^{-1}(B) = [i,1]$?

Comment: Please verify that my edit preserved the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x\in f^{-1}\left(A\cap B\right)\iff f\left(x\right)\in A\cap B\iff f\left(x\right)\in A\text{ and }f\left(x\right)\in B$.

For union you can do the same sort of thing. No numbers are involved. It involves the *preimage* of a set under function $f$ (not the inverse function).

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function and $A\subset Y$ then $f^{-1}\left(A\right)$
is defined as $\left\{ x\in X\mid f\left(x\right)\in A\right\} $.

**Edit** (continuation):

$f\left(x\right)\in A\text{ and }f\left(x\right)\in B\iff x\in f^{-1}(A)\text{ and }x\in f^{-1}\left(B\right)\iff x\in f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap f^{-1}\left(B\right)$

So we have $x\in f^{-1}\left(A\cap B\right)\iff x\in f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap f^{-1}\left(B\right)$

or shorter $f^{-1}\left(A\cap B\right)= f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap f^{-1}\left(B\right)$.

Comment: How are we conclude  f−1(A ∩ B) = f−1(A) ∩ f−1(B) from here?

Comment: see the continuation in my answer.

Comment: Where are we use interval?

Comment: In fact nowhere. In my answer I prove the 'more general situation'. And indeed it holds in a more general situation. Then automatically in a special situation where $f$, $A$ and $B$ are defined (p.e. the case of the intervals you mention and the function $f(x)=x^{2}$). You do not have to prove that apartly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by drhab addresses the main question well, but I want to discuss your attempts to find specific preimages. The big thing to keep in mind is that the domain of the functions in question is ***very*** important, here. For example, if we were dealing with $f:\{0,2\}\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x^2,$ then we would have (for example) that $$\begin{align}f^{-1}(B) &= \bigl\{x\in\{0,2\}:f(x)\in B\bigr\}\\ &= \bigl\{x\in\{0,2\}:-1\le f(x)\le 1\bigr\}\\ &= \bigl\{x\in\{0,2\}:-1\le x^2\le 1\bigr\}\\ &= \{0\}.\end{align}$$ If we were dealing (as I suspect we are supposed to) with a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ then we would instead have $$\begin{align}f^{-1}(B) &= \{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\in B\}\\ &= \{x\in\Bbb R:-1\le x^2\le 1\}\\ &= \{x\in\Bbb R:x^2\le 1\}\\ &= [-1,1].\end{align}$$ If we were dealing with a function $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C,$ then we would have $$\begin{align}f^{-1}(B) &= \{x\in\Bbb C:f(x)\in B\}\\ &= \{x\in\Bbb C:-1\le x^2\le 1\}\\ &= \{x:x\in\Bbb R,-1\le x\le 1\}\cup\{iy:y\in\Bbb R,-1\le y\le 1\}.\end{align}$$ As you can see, these are *very* different sets, even though the function has the same "rule" in each case, and we are taking the preimage of the same set.

When we're dealing with the function $f(x)=\sqrt x,$ I suspect that the domain is supposed to be $[0,\infty),$ and so we can show that $f^{-1}(B)=[0,1].$